# How to check permissions per specific user for all sites in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, user-profile

How can I check (create csv report) all permissions per specific user for ALL SharePoint site collection on SharePoint Online tenant?

Is there PowerShell script for that as I'm not aware of a report in SP Online admin centre..

I see there are scripts for SP2010/13 and I used before ControlPoint (Metalogix) to do so, but cannot find anything for SharePoint Online.

Your help is much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SPSE! No, there are no out of the box features for this. There is a "rich ecosystem" of partners that fill this need though. In addition to ControlPoint, there are offerings from SysKit, Sharegate, and Lightning Tools to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online: permission report for specific user in a site collection using PowerShell for your reference:

https://www.sharepointeurope.com/sharepoint-online-permission-report-specific-user-site-collection-using-powershell/